# AngularJS: template prints nothing on localhost server

Tags: django, angularjs

I have basic task to print something from template tag.
It works if I open html file from filesystem, but it prints nothing if I run this from django web-server.

For example:

```
<li ng-repeat="k in [0, 1, 2]">{{k}}</li>
```

Output if I open file from filesystem:

```
<li>0</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
```

And if I get file from Django web-server:

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

This problem is driving me crazy :(

Comment: If you view source on the HTML when rendered on the server, is everything the same as local?  Is Django trying to render the page, or is it just serving a static file?

Comment: Omg! You'r right, sir! Django uses it's own template engine to process {{var}}! That's why it disappears! Thank you! You can place your comment as answer and I mark it as the best one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Django is messing with the `{{}}` tags, you can change the template tags like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) { 
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('(('); 
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('))');
    });
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolateProvider

Answer (score 2):

Be careful while using `(( ))`. You can get problems with function calls inside `(( ))`.

Also note the use of third-party directives (components) that use `{{ }}`. Your configuration will break them.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108407/457375