# Smarty PHP clashing with AngularJS

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, angularjs, template-engine

How do I stop Smarty throwing an error when I'm using AngularJS in the same template. I have a Smarty page template with this code:

```
 <li ng-repeat="i in items">
      <p class="item">{{i}}</p>
 </li>
```

And I'm getting a blank page when I view in a browser. I get a big error in my apache error_log, which contains the following:

```
 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template ... <p>{{i}}</p>; unknown tag "i
```

If I swap **{{i}}** for **{{4}}** or any other digit it works fine. And I can use maths as well, {{8+2}} will show 10 in the page. Is that the Smarty doing the maths of the angularJS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items">
    <p class="item">{literal}{{i}}{/literal}</p>
</li>
```

Quote from Smarty site...

> {literal} tags allow a block of data to be taken literally. This is
>   typically used around Javascript or stylesheet blocks where {curly
>   braces} would interfere with the template delimiter syntax. Anything
>   within {literal}{/literal} tags is not interpreted, but displayed
>   as-is.

Comment: Of course! I'm new to templating engines, plus it was 2am, but the obvious answer is to escape the brackets. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 20):

Much cleaner solution: You can change the template delimiters of AngularJS thusly:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  }]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can configure Angular to use interpolation symbols other than {{}}: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108407/215945