# How to integrate PHP smarty template with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, smarty3

Am working with Smarty templating engine in PHP and want to integrate VUE.js into my application but seems like Smarty doesn't understand Vue.js syntax (double curly braces)

Code Below:

> home.tpl

```
{include file="partials/header.tpl" title="Home"} 
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
    <div class="se-pre-con"></div>

    {include file="partials/navbar.tpl"}   

    <div class="container container-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="app">
                <h2>Test Heading</h2>
                 {{ message }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{include file="partials/footer.tpl"}
```

> footer.tpl

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="resource/js/app.js"></script>
```

> app.js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

> Error Message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "file:\resource\html\templates\home.tpl" on line 11 "{{ message }}" - Unexpected "{ " <-- thrown in vendor\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 11
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12738181/6611700
Although the linked answer is for angular, the same thing applies to anyJS rendering/parsing library

Comment: Great! Thanks @riyaz_ali it worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your `app.js` use `delimiters`

```
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['%%', '%%'],
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    },
});
```

and then in `home.tpl` wrap `message` with `%%`

```
{include file="partials/header.tpl" title="Home"} 
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
    {include file="partials/navbar.tpl"}   
    <div class="container container-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="app">
                <h2>Test Heading</h2>
                 %% message %%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{include file="partials/footer.tpl"}
```