# How to render smarty inside vue?

Tags: php, vue.js, smarty

how Can I render smarty inside vue? I wanted to create vue instance on everything in my app and connect it with smarty. I want to use vue for frontend data and smarty for backend data. When I generate code like in example it appears and when vue render disappear

```
<div id="vue-app">
<div>{$smartyVariable}</div>
<div>
```

Comment: I've heard of it going the other way around (Vue.js inside Smarty): [How to integrate PHP smarty template with Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450342/how-to-integrate-php-smarty-template-with-vue-js)

Comment: I saw it, but I need Smarty inside vue, coz of rendering (seo friendly) and I have tons of code written in smarty. I can't rewrite it for vue and I don't even want do it

Comment: IMHO, you can't. Smarty is rendered on server side, Vue on frontend, so you can't pass Smarty variables directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late but... You can use the {LITERAL} in your *.tpl
Something like this:

```
<div>

    <div id="app">
        <h1>{literal}  {{ message  }} {/literal}</h1>
    </div>

{literal}
    <script>
        var myObject = new Vue(
            {
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello Vue!'
                }
            }
        );
    </script>
{/literal}
</div>
```