# Django ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-3.0

After upgrading to Django 3.0, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts'
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 580, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 565, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/alasdair/dev/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from myapp import views
  File "/Users/alasdair/dev/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts' (/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django30/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py)
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The `render_to_response` shortcut was [deprecated in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0), and is [removed in Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/3.0/#features-removed-in-3-0). You can use the `render` shortcut instead, which was added way back in Django 1.3. The `render` shortcut works similarly to `render_to_response`, but takes `request` as its first argument. Change your view as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

In your view, you have `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` as the third argument. This was deprecated in Django 1.8, and does not work in Django 1.10+.

If you are using `render_to_response` without `context_instance`, then you can pass `None` as the request to the `render` shortcut. For example, if you have,

```
return render_to_response('index.html', context)
```

then the equivalent with `render` is:

```
return render(None, 'index.html', context)
```

Note that if you pass `None` as the first argument, then your template will be rendered without any [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext). That could make the rendering slightly faster, but it might lead to CSRF errors, and means that you won't be able to access variables from the context processors (e.g. `{{ request }}` and `{{ user }}`) unless you explicitly add them to the context. I wouldn't recommend using `None` like this unless you understand these consequences.

Comment: I don't dispute the answer, the error is generated, but I note that render_to_response is *still* actually *in* shortcuts as of Django 3.2, fwiw.

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi no, the shortcut isn’t in Django 3.2, you can check the `shortcuts.py` code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2/django/shortcuts.py). You might be confusing it with the `render_to_response` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response) in class based views.

Comment: You have a lot more points that I do. so you're probably right. Last night vs code showed me a file "shortcuts.pyi". I noticed the 'i' on the end but didn't think much of it. This morning, I can't get vs code to show me anything, so I dug in myself and this time found "shortcuts.py" and it is as you describe. Thanks for the additional lesson! ;-)

Comment: The `shortcuts.pyi` is a stub file, which the vs code extension uses to help autocomplete and detect bugs. That file isn't part of your Django install.