# Why am I getting ImportError on render_to_response method if it's not included anywhere?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project, and when I want to run it locally, I get the following:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts'
```

However, I'm not including render_to_response method anywhere in the project, as I checked. I believe it's probably something like an incompatibility issue between any library, although I can't tell.

My python version is **3.7**, my Django version is **3.1**, my pip version is **20.2.2**.

My **pip freeze** returns this:

```
allauth-django==0.42.6
asgiref==3.2.10
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-filter==2.3.0
django-tables2==2.3.1
idna==2.10
mysqlclient==2.0.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
tablib==2.0.0
urllib3==1.25.10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The **full stack trace** is this:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
   self.check(display_num_errors=True)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
   databases=databases,
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
   new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
   return check_resolver(resolver)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
   return check_method()
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
   for pattern in self.url_patterns:
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
   patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
   return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\SareProject\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
   path('formats/', include('formats.urls')),
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
   urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\formats\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
   path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
   urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
   from allauth.django_utils.admin import *
 File "C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\django_utils\admin.py", line 5, in <module>
   from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts' (C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py)
```

**UPDATE**

When I try to uninstall it, and install allauth-django 0.42.0, with the command `pip install allauth-django==0.42.0`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-utils==0.4.7 (from allauth-django==0.42.0) (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-utils==0.4.7 (from allauth-django==0.42.0)
```

If I just use `pip install allauth-django`, it automatically chooses version 0.42.6.

Comment: The traceback shows you that the import is in `C:\Users\IvanH\PycharmProjects\sare_project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\django_utils\admin.py`. The latest `allauth` version is [`0.42.0`](https://pypi.org/project/django-allauth/) - I'm surprised your `pip freeze` is showing `0.42.6`. I would try uninstalling allauth and then re-installing it.

Comment: When I do so, uninstall it and reinstall with [pip install allauth-django==0.42.0], I get this:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-utils==0.4.7 (from allauth-django==0.42.0) (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-utils==0.4.7 (from allauth-django==0.42.0)

Comment: But when I just use [pip install allauth-django] it automatically chooses 0.42.6 and shows no error.

Comment: You should checkout this answer, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911435/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-render-to-response-from-django-shortcu

Comment: I saw it, but in that case he was using the method, and was a matter of using another one, since I know render_to_response is deprecated, but in my case I think it's a matter of packages, and I don't know wny is allauth in its internal code, apparently, importing that method, which has been removed in Django 3.0+

Comment: I think you should be installing `django-allauth` instead of `allauth-django`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply resolved by three steps , run these commands on your terminal in given order:

1. pip uninstall allauth-django
2. pip uninstall django-allauth
3. pip install django-allauth
   You're good to go.