# Django3, custom 404 page redirects to 500 when Debug=False because Django cannot find exception parameter

Tags: python, django, exception, django-views, django-urls

When `Debug = True` django returns a `Page not found (404)` page which is totally fine

But when I change `Debug = False` django return a `Server Error (500)` and the server shows these requests made:

```
[30/Jul/2022 12:29:44] "GET /__reload__/events/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145
[30/Jul/2022 12:29:44] "GET /__reload__/events/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145
[30/Jul/2022 12:29:44] "GET /sdfs HTTP/1.1" 500 145
[30/Jul/2022 12:29:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

myproject main `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404
handler404 = 'myproject.views.custom_page_not_found'
```

please note here that hander404 is not found by django
[handler404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaqgK.png)

my `views.py`

```
def custom_page_not_found(request, exception, template_name="errors/404.html"):
    return render(request, template_name, status=404)
```

Please not here django cannot find the `exception` parameter
[exception parameter not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgHgO.png)

In previous community questions i could not find any question that points to the `exception` parameter not found issue.  Please note that i am not using django templates `{% %}` in my `404.html` file

I think when django does not find the exception parameter it returns server error 500.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to import this handler `from django.conf.urls import handler404`.

you should simply to define variable in url:

```
handler404 = 'myproject.views.custom_page_not_found'
```

as function of view (is better) you can made this:

```
def custom_page_not_found(request, *args, template_name="errors/404.html", **kargs):
    return render(request, template_name, status=404)
```

Comment: I tried with `*args, **kargs` instead of `exception` as a parameter but it's not working and returns **server error 500** with the same log.

Comment: When i return the function with 
`return HttpResponse('<html><body>404</body></html>', status=404)` 
it works. But i don't understand why it is not working when the function is return with
`return render(request, template_name, status=404)`

Comment: Hey, thank God it works when `None` is passed as a request to render
`return render(None, 'errors/404.html', status=404)` but i have no idea why django does this?.

Comment: These posts are helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911435/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-render-to-response-from-django-shortcu & https://codehunter.cc/a/django/custom-django-404-error