# How to use Twitter typehead.js with Angular compile function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, hogan.js, typeahead.js

I am trying to use Twitter's [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) (not the Bootstrap one) along with AngularJS. I can get it all up and running just fine, until I try to get fancy use the custom **template** and **engine** options.

If I use Twitter's own Hogan.js for templating, and pass in a string template via a script tag, I am able to render the custom results that I want, but it is just pure HTML and none of the Angular directives will work.

My question is, how can I utilize the typeahead.js library and render my own custom result, and also utilize Angular's powerful compilation and two way bindings. Here is a gist with some sample code to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Gist with sample code:
https://gist.github.com/i8ramin/5690826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to use the [Typeahead library from the UI Bootstrap Angular directives](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) project instead. It doesn't really answer the question above, but thought it might be useful for others to know about the alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks, this was so much easier to integrate with Angular models

Answer (score 0):

You can switch what you use for bindings in Angular - Igor Minar answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags).

In addition, you could try tweaking the settings so that you can use Angular's template engine instead.

Comment: I don't actually have an issue with the binding syntax. It is more a question of, how do you utilize Angular JS template compiling along with the twitter typeahead.js library.