# Why template engine and angular use double mustache?

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs

I always encounter the double mustache notation {{}} in JavaScript Template engine.

Why not only one?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because they want easily distinguish Javascript object notation (single parenthesis) from template-related variables/expressions (double parenthesis: {{}}).

Answer (score 1):

It is about as much of an arbitrary design choice as can get. It definately wouldn't make sense to use `{}` as this is standard object notation, and you can in fact find notation like this in your HTML code if you are using `Knockout.js.`

Template could be signified by any marking at all, `<??>`, `[[]]`,`!><!`, and in fact most template engines you can customize to use those if you prefer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags for how to customize the notation in angular.