# How do I implement user registration with Django and AngularJS?

Tags: django, authentication, angularjs

I have a good knowledge in Django, and I have just learnt AngularJS. I am struggling to implement a login/registration page. I am not sure if I should serve the Angular inside the django app or completely separate it from the django and serve it on another domain.

How should I implement user registration with Django and AngularJS?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application and how you intend to use AngularJS.

If it is simply about login/registration, using the built-in auth module from Django is often enough ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)).

Once the registration is done, you can have a strong coupling between the Django templating and AngularJS. It works well once you have resolved the conflicting template tags ([solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags))

The last part that can be tricky if you have the csrf protection on is how you get your queries though. You can either generate the form from the Django server. Unfortunately, it kind of defeats the purpose of having angularjs as you are back to performing "classical" POST.

Another option is to get the cookie using ngCookies (available [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/)) and to add it to `$httpProvider.defaults`. That way, the CSRF token will be automatically added.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies']);
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    app.$httpProvider = $httpProvider;
});
app.run(['$cookies', function($cookies) {
    app.$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
    app.$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
    app.$httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = {'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']};
}]);
```

That should get you started on authentication with Django and AngularJS.