# ng-repeat in django template

Tags: angularjs, django-templates

Am trying to output some stuff in my template using directive `ng-repeat` and am not getting the right thing. Perhaps there is something am missing

`<div ng-init="friends = [` 
      `{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},`
      `{name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},`
      `{name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},`
      `{name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'}`
    `]">`

`<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends" >
      {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
        </li>`

This is the output I get

`who is years old.`
`who is years old.`
`who is years old.`
`who is years old.`

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just to check, is the `<div <div` typo in your actual code or just here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags ? you might also want to write properly the code in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because `{{ variable }}` is a language syntax of django template:

> Variables look like this: {{ variable }}. When the template engine encounters a variable, it evaluates that variable and replaces it with the result.

But you need to output `{{friend.name}}` as it. If you're using django 1.5+, you can use `{% verbatin %}` block:

```
{% verbatim %}
    Your template here
{% endverbatim %}
```