# how to use angular expression inside template's tag of django?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-templates

I wrote in tags.py the following tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def getUserName(request, user_id):
    return foo(user_id)
```

In my html template I combined django symbol {{ }} together with angular symbol {[{ }]} 
([AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)).
so I wrote there this expression:

```
{% getUserName request {[{ angular_conversation.user_id }]} %}
```

The problem is the django parser it before angularjs parses the internal expression.
Please tell me how can I cause it works...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use an angular expression as a template tag argument. The template tag is processed on the server side before the response is sent to the client, where angular is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have to think about, a workaround. From Django 1.5 you have the `{% verbatim %}` tag that prevents anything in it from rendering (including `{{}}` signs).

`{% getUserName request {[{ angular_conversation.user_id }]} %}` for what you are using this for? Can't you do it like `{{ request.user.username }}`?

Comment: this is not the same username in my case...
I used rest_api in angular to get query of conversations
and then I used ng-repeat on angular_conversations 
and I want to display on the screen the user name of each angular_conversation... but from the query I have only their IDs, which are the foreign keys for the models with their usernames...

so I want to use django in order to translate these parameters...

Comment: Hi McAbra,
I wrote the full problem I tackled in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040750/how-to-include-in-queryset-details-fields-of-a-foreign-key-django-and-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

Change your default Django template delimiters or Angular's interpolation delimiters (see [$interpolateProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolateProvider)).

Something like:

```
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});
```

Would allow you to use '//' in your templates, which would avoid the conflict.

```
//myScopeObject.something//
```

Comment: Hi, I did it, as written in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags
The problem is not because they have same symbols...