# Angular JS + Django - Referencing static files

Tags: django, angularjs

I've written my first angular app for handling a rather complex multi-file upload process within a Django app. Everything is working great and I'm loving Angular. However, I stumbled on a simple problem referencing image sources. It's not critical for my app, but I wanted to add a simple spinner/whirligig image while the files are uploading.

In my non-Angular Django templates this is dead simple:

```
<img src='{% static 'whirligig.gif' %}'>
```

This doesn't work inside Angular views due to the Angular/Django template syntax conflict. Of course, I can hard-code my Django STATIC_URL path or use a relative path from the Angular partial, but I'd prefer not to. Am I missing something simple here or is this just an unfortunate product of mixing two MVC frameworks?

Comment: Take a look, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags

Comment: @alecxe, Thanks, I'm starting to think this is messy any which way I cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) tag?

I guess you can do something like:

```
{% verbatim %}{{ {% endberbatim %}{% static 'whirligig.gif' %}{% verbatim %} }}{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: James, my entire app is wrapped in verbatim in a parent Django base template. I think you are suggesting to escape the verbatim and re-enable the tag but this doesn't work. Can you elaborate?

Comment: if your whole app is wrapped in verbatim, you can still place {% endverbatim %} wherever you want django template to generate stuff for you and then place another {% verbatim %} to continue your angular content.