# Is it possible to change django's template tag {{?

Tags: django

Given that i already have a large angularjs based code with template tag as `{{` - is it possible to change django's template tag to maybe `{[{` .. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)

Comment: The answers provide only a way of changing angular's template tag. I already have written a lot of code so i'm looking into changing django's tag.

Comment: This will have to be the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update***

Perhaps dynamically patch it

```
import re
import django.template.base
django.template.base.VARIABLE_TAG_END = '}]}'
django.template.base.VARIABLE_TAG_START = '{[{'
django.template.base.tag_re = re.compile(ur'(\{\%.*?\%\}|\{\[\{.*?\}\]\}|\{\#.*?\#\})')
reload(django.template)
```

Put this in `__init__.py` of your any apps and see if it works.

---

No simple way currently, they are [hardcoded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0d912258921a442c48d5787228db2db5af7e8fa5/django/template/base.py#L44):

```
VARIABLE_TAG_START = '{{'
VARIABLE_TAG_END = '}}'
```

Anyway, you could patch your local installation or forked version.