# Apply a piece of config to several controllers

Tags: angularjs, configuration

I'm using AngularJS and Django together, so I apply the recipe [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108407/223424) to reconfigure Angular's template delimiters:

```
angular.module("some module name").config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

I have to re-apply this piece to each module, only changing the `"some module name"` string. Is there a way to define this piece of configuration once, and then cleanly require and inject it into a module at the module's definition site?

Comment: Isn't `$interpolateProvider` a provider? That should mean you only need to do it once in your primary module config...

Comment: @MattWay: I have several independent modules. Do you propose to create another module, apply the config to it, and make the target modules require that configured module? I'm new to Angular; I's appreciate an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$interpolateProvider` is a provider, any change to it will affect not only the current module but also all the modules that depends on it.

You can, for example, define a "config" module and add it as dependency to other modules:

```
angular.module('config', []).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

And on the other modules:

```
angular.module('module1', ['config']);
angular.module('module2', ['config']);
```

**[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sVsgbtIfxAHCBovuBv1Q?p=preview)**