# change interpolate for specific controllor in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am buiding an app using angular and django. So now out of the partials, the code clashes beacause of `{{}}` .

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .config(function($interpolateProvider){
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
 });
```

This changes interpolate symbol for whole app but  i want to change `$interpolate` only for specific controller. Can somebody show the way to achieve this?

Comment: there is no way to change the interpolation for a single controller, short of putting that controller in it's own module.

Comment: so does that mean i have to change my whole code according to new interpolate symbols?

Comment: interpolation isn't the responsibility of a *controller*, it happens before the controllers are even instantiated.  Unless you provide a bit more code illustrating your actual issue, the assumption is that you mean you have an HTML template which you want to use django expressions and the expressions from a controller both at the same time.  Not only is this generally a bad practice, it's also definitely not possible to selectively handle interpolation differently in that manner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)