# Using a angularjs variable in a django template

Tags: django, angularjs, templates

I am trying to pass to my templatetag (registered with simple_tag) a angularjs value as argument by doing the following in my template:

```
{% my_template_tag {$ item.value $} %}
```

However, this simply doesn't work, I tried a couple of other things as adding quotes, by it just doesn't work.

Any idea here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can't** do that. Template tags are server side while angularjs is rendered in client side. The value of the angularjs variable won't be available until the client's browser renders it.

If you have to do that, this variable should be calculated in the Django view and not in angularjs.