# angular JS installed but not loading, in Django app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I have a practice app and Angular JS installed through NPM on my machine at work. I call it in my base.htm which all templates extend:

```
{% block main_header %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sitename</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static "screen.css" %}" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            {% block js %}{% endblock %}
        </script>
    </head>
{% endblock %}
```

I just tried reinstalling it to be certain, it is installed. At
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default there is an example, and I put it in my django app at business_index.html as so:

```
{% extends 'base.htm' %}

{% block body_block %}

    ....some code

<div ng-app="">

    <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The some code beforehand isn't the problem, I temporarily deleted it and refreshed. Why is my text not displaying next to hellp like in the example? I must not have configured it well. Thank you

Comment: When you call `{{name}}` it is a django variable or angular one?

Comment: that will be an angular one, I got it from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never worked with Django + AngularJS before, I will assume that you are trying to use `{{ variable }}` in your template.

That syntax will try to render a Django variable from the view (passed by [context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse.context_data)).

You will need to change the AngularJS tags:

```
myModule.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

**EDIT**

Example:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

After you do this, when you want to call a variable or angular expression in your template you will use `{[{angular_variable}]}`, and when you want to call a Django variable you will use `{{django_variable}}`

Also you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108407/3945375) and the AngularJS [documentation for this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108407/3945375)

Comment: where should I most likely be putting this myModule.config? Is in the base.htm upper level <script> tags good?  Also, what is myModule referring to, the template I end up calling it from maybe?