# Overriding AngularJS template tags in Django, with previous solution not configured properly

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, templatetags

I am trying to override Angular tags of {{ }} based on this answer [AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags/11108407#11108407), in my django app, but I am not getting it to recognize the override...in base.htm I have:

```
{% block main_header %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sitename</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static "screen.css" %}" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            scheduleApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
                $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
                $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
            });
            {% block js %}{% endblock %}
        </script>
    </head>
{% endblock %}
```

In the template I have:

```
{% extends 'base.htm' %}

{% block body_block %}

<div ng-app="scheduleApp">

    <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>

    <h1>Hello
            {{ name }} [[ name ]]
    </h1>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I get

[image]

I get how it ignores the nonexistent {{ name }}, but why is this override not working? Typing into the input does nothing visible. Thank you

Comment: Not an answer: Have you considered disassociating AngularJS from django and not serving up angularjs inside of Django templates?  Decoupling is the bees knees of maintainable software engineering.  Then you can host your angularjs files as static files.

Comment: that would probably be best

Comment: what is the general idea for that? Is it similar to this post https://coderwall.com/p/bzjuka/set-up-drf-to-play-well-with-angular-templates?p=1&q=

Comment: Well.  I'd recommend Django Rest Framework with AngularJS.  Basically, your AngularJS app is completely standalone and your Django backend is a glorified database wrapper.  Then, when AngularJS needs content from the database, you do ajax requests (`$http.get()`, `$http.post()`, et c.)  It creates a very strong front-end/back-end separation.  Since you only talk to the backend via the ajax calls, it opens up the possibility of implementing other front-end clients.  iOS, Android, desktop, _arduino_ ( one of my systems really does have arduino sensors that do `HTTP POST`'s to update the server.

Comment: [This is what I read when I started.](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html)