# Can I stop rendering variables in Django?

Tags: python, django, vue.js

So,

can I somehow stop django rendering specific template variables?

Background is, that I wanted to try vuejs in a django app, 
which kind of worked.

Problem is, both share the same syntax for variables.

So in vuejs you declare them like

```
{{ message }}
```

And djangos template engine interprete it as a django template variable and try to render it. Because it doenst exist, it disappear and vuejs isnt working anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Vue's docs](http://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters), its template tag delimiters can be changed to something else, like `{!! !!}`, if you want.

If that is not an option, [Django has a `{% verbatim %}` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812653/1558430) that can escape parts of your template containing Vuejs tags.

Comment: I swear I thought there's a way to change Django's tags as well, but I cannot find it. Maybe I am thinking of Jinja2? (Which also works with Django)

Comment: OK, it appears that's Jinja2. Django has [this to say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#limitations-with-string-literals): "Django’s template language has no way to escape the characters used for its own syntax." There are a couple of inconvenient workarounds listed at that link.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist [it's hard coded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L99)

Comment: thanks thats it!
I guess changing vues tags is the best solution.

Comment: It seems like `{% verbatim %}` is the most elegant way to use Django with Vue.