# django-angular unable to use filter tags inside templates

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

I have **django** that is **serving api** as well as static files including **html files**, inside html I'm using angular

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
             <div ng-view></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/static/views/home.html',
            controller: 'index_ctrl'
        })
    }
]);
```

home.html

```
<div class="blog-post" ng-repeat="x in data">
    <p class="blog-post-title"><a href="">{{ x.title }}</a></p>
    <p class="blog-post-meta"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp{{ x.pub_date|date  }}</i> </p>
    {{ x.description|limitTo:'50'}}
    <p><a href="">See more</a></p>
    <hr />
</div>
```

I find angular filter **does not limit** my text, instead outputs all the text....What could be alternative option?

I also tried to use django filter tag `{{ x.description|truncatewords:'50'}}` but angular threw error `Error: Unknown provider: truncatewordsFilterProvider <- truncatewordsFilter`

Any help on this is appreciated....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use angularjs with django templating language their template tags conflict.
You will find solution in the link below 
[AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't accesible calling any Django templatetag/filter once the HTML is rendered, only if you refresh the page you are calling again any request to Django and its filters will be processed.

If you are using the open braces **{{** and need to avoid Django about using it you need to use the **{% templatetag openvariable %}** and for closing braces **}}** **{% templatetag closevariable %}** instead.

Of course that **'truncatewords'** filter wont work because ***it is a Django filter, not Angular.***