# Not able to access controller variables on view using {{}} in angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs

I have an angular app deployed on Google App Engine (python).

Whenever I try to access controller variables on View using {{}} notation, nothing happens.

Controller

```
$scope.abc ="ABC"
```

On view

```
<h2>{{abc}}</h2>
```

This works if I run my app on local without app engine. but after deployment same code does not work.

I have googled this but didn't get anything. What is the issue with {{}} ?

Comment: We can't possibly solve this without code

Comment: did your angular template code  is within verbatim tag?

Comment: check if you added ng-app and ng-controller as attributes... or if you use routes check if you used the right controller in the configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace the {{}} tag

because the python django use it also
        var myApp = angular.module('DemoProject', []);

```
    myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
        });
    myApp.run(function ($rootScope) {

    });
```

use it {$ $} will work

Comment: I have got the same solution and answered :)

Answer (score 1):

There is conflict with {{}} expression of angular and python/webapp. So I used $interpolateProvider to change the {{}} with ////

```
app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});
```

Here is one more post related with this

[AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)